# Animation Methods, Simplification and Repairing

Tags: c#, wpf

**Context**

I'm kinda new at animating WPF stuff, but I've played around with a library or two and I "had" an animation that I used with the Window control in WPF, this is an example of that method, keep in mind that this method works:

```
public void AnimateFadeWindow(object sender, double opacity, double period)
    {
        //Tab item is a enw tab item (the sender is casted to this type.)

        Window win = (Window)sender;

        win.Opacity = 0;

        //using the doubleanimation class, animation is a new isntancem use the parameter opacity and set the period to a timespan.
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(opacity, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(period));

        //begin the animation on the object.
        win.BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, animation);
    }
```

**Problem**

Like I said previously, This code works, the problem with this code was, of course, it's only suited to the Window control, it won't work with other controls, for instance, TabItem, Button or any other control I wanted to use it for, so I "Upgraded" my method and this is my CURRENT method:

```
public void AnimateFade(object sender, double opacity, double period)
    {
        //using the doubleanimation class, animation is a new isntancem use the parameter opacity and set the period to a timespan.
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(opacity, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(period));

        Object obj = sender.GetType();

        if (obj is TabItem)
        {
            TabItem tab = (TabItem)sender;
            tab.BeginAnimation(TabItem.OpacityProperty, animation);
        }
        else if (obj is Label)  
        {
            Label lab = (Label)sender;
            lab.BeginAnimation(Label.OpacityProperty, animation);
        }
        else if (obj is Window)
        {
            Window win = (Window)sender;

            win.Opacity = 0;
            win.BeginAnimation(Window.OpacityProperty, animation);
        }
    }
```

This method doesn't work. I don't really know what I'm doing wrong here, so I wondered if someone could possibly help out.

ALSO, is there an easier way to do this using something like the PropertyInfo class or a reflection class?

Thanks Stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is nothing to do with `Animation`.The problem is you are comparing `sender.Type` while you should compare `sender` itself i.e.
use `if (sender is TabItem)` instead of `if (obj is TabItem)`.

Moreover, There is no need to compare sender with `TabItem`, `Lable`, `Window` and etc one by one, they are all `UIElements`! and Since `UIElement` implements `IAnimatable`, you just need to cast `sender` to `UIElement` and you have a general method that applies your animation to any control :

```
    public void AnimateFade(object sender, double opacity, double period)
    {
        UIElement element = (UIElement)sender;
        element.Opacity = 0;
        DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(opacity, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(period));
        element.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, animation);
    }
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't know I could backtrack to UIElements and use that instead, that's pretty interesting.